# Retrieving a User's name from FireBase Auth Given a UID

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

In my Flutter app I create records in Firebase, then store the current user's FirebaseAuth UID with each record. My goal was to later retrieve a user's name from FirebaseAuth given the UID. I don't want to store each user's display name in the DB because that can change.

I looked through the documentation, but don't see that listed anywhere.

There are probably security reasons that they won't let you do this.

Comment: You're correct, it's a security issue. You'll need a database.